# Can I use the effect of the Winged Dragon of Ra from the Yu-Gi-Oh! anime in a real game?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

The anime says that the Winged Dragon of Ra's attack and defense is what is added up by the attack and defense of the tributes to summon it. [From the Yu-Gi-Oh wiki](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Trivia:The_Winged_Dragon_of_Ra):

> When Summoned by Tributing 3 monsters, the ATK and DEF of "Ra" become the combined ATK and DEF of the Tributed monsters.

The [card that is legal for tournaments](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/The_Winged_Dragon_of_Ra) does not say that on the card. Is the anime effect OK to use in a actual card game?

Similarly, people are saying how you can give life points for the attack like in the anime, but I'm asking if we can use the effect in a duel.

Comment: Of all the questions I have seen on stack exchange so far, this one is the most astonishing.

Answer (score 4):

Effects from the *Yu-Gi-Oh!* anime do not apply to the card game, especially not in a legal tournament. You can only use the text that is actually on the card (and any modifications due to errata or official rulings).

Of course, in a friendly game, you and your opponent are welcome use those affects if you agree. If you want to play that way, nothing is stopping you.

Answer (score 0):

No that effect is only the effect of the anime card Ra's attack is made by paying life points as read on the card

> You can pay Life Points so that you only have 100 left; this card
>   gains ATK and DEF equal to the amount of Life Points paid.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not in a tournament. You would have to use the printed effect, but if you can get the people you are playing against (in a casual setting) to agree to the change in effect, sure you can! (Most people wouldn't want to play you if you had that though, even if it requires the tribute of three monsters)

Summary: As house rules, yes. In a tournament, no.